# Sort user input from lowest to highest

Tags: javascript

I need to sort the order of user input from lowest to highest and print into my p id.

Implement a sort algorithm to sort n integers (without using sort() method of array).

Print sorted array in the output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>User Input, Sort and Find!</title>

<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Enter 4 numbers user!</h2>
<p id="myprint"></p>

<button onclick="userInput()">Input your Numbers!</button>
<button onclick="searchInput()">Find an inputed number in your array!       </button>
<script>
var numbers = [];

function userInput() {
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   var num = prompt("Enter a number 1 at a time, from 1-9 until prompts ask you 4 times:");
   if (isNaN(num)) {
     alert("Enter a number!");
    --i; // reset the counter for amount of numbers entered
   }
   if( !isNaN(num)) {
      if( num % 1 != 0){
         alert("Enter a whole number!")
         --i;  // reset the counter for amount of numbers entered
      }else{
         numbers.push(num);
      }
   }
}
document.getElementById("myprint").innerHTML = "Your numbers are" + numbers;
//Sort the array and print numbers in inner html
function bubbleSort(numbers) {  
    var length = numbers.length;
    for (var i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = (length - i); j > 0; j--) {
            if (numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]) {
                var nmbr = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = nmbr;
            }
        }
    }
}
function searchInput() {

}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is `array.sort()` not allowed?

Comment: What does your current code actually do when you run it? In the code shown you never actually call `bubbleSort()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code works, except that you have to actually call the bublesort function and then that function needs to return the results.

```
<body>
<h2>Enter 4 numbers user!</h2>
<p id="myprint"></p>

<button onclick="userInput()">Input your Numbers!</button>
<button onclick="searchInput()">Find an inputed number in your array!       </button>
<script>
var numbers = [];

function userInput() {
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   var num = prompt("Enter a number 1 at a time, from 1-9 until prompts ask you 4 times:");
   if (isNaN(num)) {
     alert("Enter a number!");
    --i; // reset the counter for amount of numbers entered
   }
   if( !isNaN(num)) {
      if( num % 1 != 0){
         alert("Enter a whole number!")
         --i;  // reset the counter for amount of numbers entered
      }else{
         numbers.push(num);
      }
   }
}

numbers = bubbleSort(numbers);

document.getElementById("myprint").innerHTML = "Your numbers are" + numbers;
//Sort the array and print numbers in inner html
function bubbleSort(numbers) {  
    var length = numbers.length;
    for (var i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = (length - i); j > 0; j--) {
            if (numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]) {
                var nmbr = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = nmbr;
            }
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}
function searchInput() {

}
}
</script>

</body>
```

Here's a [fiddle that works](https://jsfiddle.net/d5nr2Lkp/)

Comment: Thanks man, I can't believe I didn't notice that lol.  I am tired.

Comment: Happens to all of us, no worries. :)